# How to Remote-Sync IPad Calendar with Outlook

Tags: ipad, calendar, ms-office

Without installing ITunes, and without attaching my IPad3 to my PC, I want to synchronize my IPad calendar with my Outlook calendar.

I thought I could make this work by creating the following Outlook rule:

`"Send an alert to my mobile device when I get messages from someone"`

With the option:

`"Which is a meeting invitation or update"`

I then specifiy that I want the invite forwarded to my gmail account, which my IPad is linked to.

I don't know if this would have worked, because this Outlook rule doesn't seem to execute when a meeting invite arrives.  However, when I attempt to manually forward a meeting invite I've received, I notice that an ical attachment is present.  I can then manually add it to my calendar.  Not so bad!

However, it would be even cooler if the IPad "auto-added" the ical notice to my calendar as the emails (with icals attached) arrive.  Is there a way to configure an auto-accept (particularly an auto-accept from a specific e-mail address)?

p.s. And while we're discussing this, does anyone know why Outlook would fail to execute the rule I defined?

Comment: I found your question a bit confusing. Could you say exactly what you're trying to do, in one sentence? Please include the program(s) you want to use for each piece.

Comment: Are you using Exchange for email?

Comment: @Timothy: Without installing ITunes, and without attaching my IPad3 to my PC, I want to synchronize my IPad calendar with my Outlook calendar.

Comment: @Matt: Yes, using Exchange

Comment: @BrentArias Wow, that's totally not what I thought the question was—I thought you wanted a way to auto-accept iCal invitations with Outlook or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure Exchange on your iPad by:

1. Open **Settings**
2. Go to **Mail, Contacts, Calendars**
3. Tap on **Add Account**
4. Tap on **Microsoft Exchange**
5. Fill in the information for your company's Exchange account. You may need to get this from your IT department.
6. Check the Mail, Calendars or Contacts sliders as necessary.

Open the Calendars app and you're good to go.

Comment: I will accept this as my answer, even though my client's security policy forbids that my personal IPad has exchange account information.

Comment: Sometimes they allow you to have exchange on there as long as you have a passcode on the iPad. Is this the case or do they have any mobile device access disabled?